# How do I add additional APIs to existing Azure API Manager using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management

New to Terraform and as the question states I want to add additional APIs to an existing API Manager instance.  Below is the example Terraform and this works fine.  But I want to add a second api.  Is it absolutely required that I put it inline in this Terraform script?  The reason I ask is, If my team develops "example api" and a second team develops "awesomeexample api" can they have the Terraform code they need just for the api resource in their repository?  Do I need to get the name of the API Manager through Powershell or GraphAPI?  **Edit:**  Right now when I add an additional api resource it destroys the first.  I am guessing this is because of Terraform state...but that is not the behavior I want.  I just want to keep adding apis or altering them independently of the api manager.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "example-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "example-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "Example API"
  path                = "example"
  protocols           = ["https"]

  import {
    content_format = "swagger-link-json"
    content_value  = "http://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net/?format=json"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the `terraform plan` says?

Answer (score 0):

Me, I've been putting each API in it's own tf file.

Like for your example api, I'd create a api-example.tf file, cut/paste the azurerm_api_management_api block into it.

terraform init/plan/apply should still just work.

To add a new API into this API Mgmt instance, just copy api-example.tf to api-newapi.tf, edit as appropriate (name/displayname/path/import, and poof, new api.

I don't like using the same instance name for multiple different resources. here you used example three times, an RG, APIM, and APIM_API.  it gets confusing and may break the minute you add a new API also referenced as 'example'. I use thisrg, ex-apim, and example-api (since your original API is called example). Your awsomeexample api I'd call awesome-api or something like that to differentiate example-api vs awesomeexample-api

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a similar thing that led me here.

One of our developers had added his resource by modifying our terraform files, planned it and applied it. By doing that he modified the remote state, but he never commited his changes. Thus when we were going to apply the terraform files from master, the locally planned state did not match what was in the remote.

In your case though, it is hard to tell. If you define two APIs in the same file that collide (e.g. 2x resource `"azurerm_api_management_api" "example"`) that might cause you issues.